# postgreSQL: grant select on all tables in schema FOO to FOOROLE

Tags: database-schema, privileges, sql-grant, postgresql-9.2

EDIT: Found it.  I thought USAGE was an explanation, not a key word.  :-)

What else must occur in addition to

```
 GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES    IN SCHEMA FOO to FOOROLE
```

in order for FOOROLE to be able to select from, say,  FOO.CUSTOMER?   Is there some general schema-access privilege that must also be granted?

FOOROLE was created with LOGIN and can log into the database, but is being denied:

```
   ERROR:  permission denied for schema foo
   LINE 1: select * from foo.customer


   ********** Error **********

   ERROR: permission denied for schema foo
   SQL state: 42501
   Character: 15  (caret points to the first character of "foo")
```

Comment: is connected user in FOOROLE?

Comment: Please post this as an answer to your question or delete the question, rather than leaving it open.

Comment: @Craig Ringer: one must deal with arbitrary rules that prevent a question from being answered by the questioner until a certain amount of time has elapsed.  I went to bed while that time was still pending. But today is another day.

Comment: @Craig Ringer: and now that I've answered my question, I cannot accept it as the correct answer until tomorrow, so please don't tell me not to leave the answer in an unaccepted state :-)

Comment: @Tim Sorry about that. It's really frustrating that Stack Overflow doesn't allow other people to see timers/limits like that, especially as the timers/limits vary with site reputation. Quite a pain. It should let you post an answer and show it as "pending" until the timer expires, or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USAGE is the generic permission I was seeking.

Comment: `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA FOO TO FOOROLE;`